# Remove element from joined list and also remove from original list - python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
>>> players = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
>>> viewers = ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

Now participant  'b' is leaving the game.  I don't know whether the participant is a player or viewer, so I joined the lists:

```
>>> participants = players + viewers
>>> participants
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

and then remove 'b' from the joined list:

```
>>> participants.remove['b']
>>> participants
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

However, 'b' is not removed from the original list:

```
>>> players
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I understand that this is the expected behaviour.

My question is, in Python, is there a way to remove an element from a joined list and also impact the original list?

My current workaround is just to check the original list of players, and then the original list of viewers, but that seems like there should be a more Pythonic way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 2D array could do it.

```
players = ['a', 'b', 'c']
viewers= ['d', 'e', 'f']
participants = [players,viewers]
print(participants)

# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

for i in participants:
    try:
        i.remove("a")
    except:
        pass

print(participants) # [['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
print(players) # ['b', 'c']
```

Comment: Yes this works. But note that you have not mutated `players`, which is now also contained in participants. OP's question involved flattening `players` into the new list, which implied copying it. In such case it is not possible that any changes in the new list modify the original

Comment: @yatu Yes,but if you copy the list,it won't change the origin list after you change the joined list.....I think there is a better idea.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that this does not do what OP asked (even though it has been accepted)

Comment: Hmmmm,But OP seems just want to change the origin list when he change the joined list.In this way,`copy` will pass the value instead of address.

Comment: Sure yes. It's not what I'm trying to imply though. But anyway it seems to solve it for OP, so there you go :)

Comment: @yatu Haaaaa......,Sorry for my bad English.Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`players + viewers` this creates a new list and you are removing from this new list.

There's nothing really 'unpythonic' when you have two data structures to perform operation on each one of them.

If you want to do it in a single operation you can wrap both `players` and `viewers` in a class and have a `remove` method on that class that would then remove from both players and viewers, this way you would hide that 'ugly' operation. But I think that's not really worth it.

Comment: i was hoping because it is a shallow copy, there might be a way.  For example, if i update  an attribute of a participant, e.g. participants[2].name = 'Eric', this updates the original list

Comment: @EricD'Souza it's a collection of objects and you are updating a particular object, it works. if you modify your lists for example it won't have any effect on the new list.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but only if you modify *in-place* one of the lists. As soon as you *add* one list to another, this will create a new list, and changes on this *new* list will not be reflected on the original list. In that sense there's nothing you can do here, since calling `__add__` will always create a copy.

In order to modify it in place you could do the following:

```
players = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
viewers = ['d', 'e', 'f'] 

id(players)
# 112230613128
```

Now `extend` with `viewers` and `remove` `'b'`:

```
players.extend(viewers)
players.remove('b')
```

And you'll see that the updated list is still the original one:

```
players
# ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

id(players)
# 112230613128
```

Comment: You could use `players.remove("e")` and `print(viewers)`.the list `viewers` has no change.

Answer (score 1):

To me the best way to do this would be to create a list of lists and iterate through to remove a player. This would impact both your nested list as well as the original.

Let's see the code below.

```py
# Establish the lists
>>> players = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
>>> viewers = ['d', 'e', 'f']

# Create nested list
>>> participants = [players, viewers]
>>> participants
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']] 

# Define the player that left the game (can be assigned however)
>>> player_left = 'a'

# List comprehension to remove the player from the nested list structure
participants = [l.remove(player_left) if player_left in l else l for l in participants]

# See the result
>>> participants
[['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

# And we can see that this has, in-fact, updated the original list
>>> players
['b', 'c']
```

**Hopefully this helps ! :)**

Comment: Thanks Darien for the detailed explanation! I have already accepted a similar answer from @jizhihaoSAMA :(